# Scraping data from a specific table

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape each of the symbol codes and names from here (about 1/4 of the way down the page): https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT?p=MSFT&.tsrc=fin-srch

[image]

If I inspect the HTML of the first row with the symbol AAPL I am given the following

```
<tr class="Va(t) Bdc($seperatorColor) TapHc(h) Fw(500) Bgc($hoverBgColor):h H(44px) BdT"</tr>
```

So in my VBA I navigate to the webpage by creating an internetexplorer object and then the first piece of code to actually begin the **scraping** is the following:

```
Dim allRowOfData As Variant
Set allRowOfData = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("Va(t)")
Dim myValue As String
myValue = allRowOfData.Cells(1).innerHTML
```

If I look in the immediate window I am then presented with so many HTMLElements (20) plus all of their children that I have no idea where to begin, to be able to get the data that I want.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Also, how do we know what to put in the getElementsByClassName? Initially I had the entire string after the `<tr class=`  and this returned nothing at all.

Comment: I see five symbol codes and names. Do you just want the first?

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld I would want all five of them. And then later I will (if it is possible) pass each one as a parameter to get specific data from a different site for them.

Comment: In Excel, it seems you can get that data fairly easily using Power Query.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Unfortunately I don't have Power Query, so am needing to do it via code.

Comment: What version of Excel? PQ is available from Excel 2010+

Comment: I will try and download it. But I'd still be interested in seeing how this is done with code.